# Adding images to master page. base url changes dependent on what content page is on?

Tags: html, css

I have a master page where I display images.

```
<img src="../Images/footer_faq.png" alt="faq" />
<img src="../Images/footer_feedback.png" alt="feedback" />
```

This works for most of my pages, But if I navigate to a page inside of a folder the images don't work anymore. The folder name is added before /images/

> Exampe:
>
> www.mysite.com/Images/footer_faq.png -- works
>
> as I navigate
>
> www.mysite.com/Public/Images/footer_faq.png -- does not work

What is the best way to prevent this as so my images on the master page will display no mater what content page I navigate to.

Comment: Use the absolute path and not the relative path. (relative being relative to the master file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have this tree, with a `DocumentRoot` of `/`

```
 - /
  - Public/
    -Images/
      - ...
  - Pages/
    - ...
  - index.html
```

Assume that `index.html` is your master page.

Now, assume we are on `index.html`

- The **relative** path to `Images` would be `Public/Images/`
- The **absolute** path to `Images` would be `/Public/Images/`

Now, assume we are on `Pages/about.html`

- The **relative** path to `Images` would be `../Public/Images/`
- The **absolute** path to `Images` would be `/Public/Images/`

As you can see, the **absolute** path won't change depending on the page you're on.

This would result in your `<img` tags becoming;

```
<img src="/Images/footer_faq.png" alt="faq" />
<img src="/Images/footer_feedback.png" alt="feedback" />
```

*Change them to the way your document tree is designed*